# Turbo Vector Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to pass a turbo ([www.turbo360.co](http://www.turbo360.co)) vector through an ajax call but I can't get it to work correctly. Here is my code:

```
    var message = 'New order created: Name: ' + orderInfo.name + ' \n Room: ' + orderInfo.room + ' Payment: ' + orderInfo.payment + ' Dorm: ' + orderInfo.dorm + ' Sugar: ' + orderInfo.sugar + ' Splenda: ' + orderInfo.splenda + ' Milk: ' + orderInfo.milk + ' Iced: ' + orderInfo.iced
    message += ' Creme: ' + orderInfo.creme
    var sent = false

    $.ajax({
        url:'https://production.turbo360-vector.com/expresso-eeonzr/sms?message=' + message + '&to=3476749151&key=b64dd743-3760-4425-bafd-37d99cce97b4',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(msg){
            console.log("This worked");
        }
    })
```

Anyone know why my `console.log` doesn't go through?

Comment: "does not work correctly" is not helpful problem description. please provide more detail on the issue you are facing.

Comment: How should we know? Add an error handler to find out yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these parameters to the ajax call:

```
dataType: "json",
error: (err) => { 
    console.log(err);
}
```

If that does not work, try checking the Method type of your vector in your project dashboard and make sure it makes whatever you specify in 'type' in your ajax call (i.e. 'GET', 'POST', etc).